# How to call `apply` on a superclass in Scala?

Tags: scala, inheritance, overriding, superclass, super

My class inherits from some base class, and implements `apply` method with exactly the same signature as the base's one. I want to call base's `apply` method from my class.
When I try following:

```
class MyClass extends BaseClass {
  def apply(k: String, v: String) = {
    super.apply(k, v)
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I got `value apply is not a member of BaseClass...` compile error.
How should I call base's apply method from the child class?

Also, why it is possible to override `apply` method without an `override` keyword?

EDIT: Actual code:

```
class OAuthParamsBuilder(helper: OAuthParamsHelper)
extends KeyValueHandler {

  def apply(k: String, v: String): Unit = {
    ...
  }
}

class OAuthInitSupportBuilder
extends OAuthParamsBuilder(StandardOAuthParamsHelper) {

  /*override*/ def apply(k: String, v: String): Unit = {
    super.apply(k, v)
    ...
  }
...
}
```

EDIT: I've noticed that KeyValueHandler is a trait, this may be an issue.

```
trait KeyValueHandler extends ((String, String) => Unit)
```

Comment: Could you add the code for the `BaseClass` ?

Comment: Does the issue survives if you clean and recompile everything ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not helping us help you, but I suspect this is the true definition of `apply` on the base class:

```
def apply(kv: (String, String)) = ???
```

**EDIT**

The code you pasted is not enough, as the problem is not reproducible with it:

```
trait OAuthParamsHelper
trait KeyValueHandler
class OAuthParamsBuilder(helper: OAuthParamsHelper) extends KeyValueHandler {
  def apply(k: String, v: String): Unit = ???
}
object StandardOAuthParamsHelper extends OAuthParamsHelper
class OAuthInitSupportBuilder extends OAuthParamsBuilder(StandardOAuthParamsHelper) {
  override def apply(k: String, v: String): Unit = {
    super.apply(k, v)
    ???
  }
}
```

Comment: @lpaul7 I could not reproduce the issue with the code you posted.